# Using pragma in .c and .h file

Tags: global, compiler-warnings, extern, greenhills

I am using pragma like this in .c file:

```
#pragma ghs startdata
#pragma ghs section bss=".BSS"
static int A;
#pragma ghs section bss=default
#pragma ghs enddata
```

in .h file:

```
extern int A;
```

When i build with Greenhill compiler, it shows this waring:
**incompatibility associated with redeclaration of variable "A": data type differs from earlier declaration's unspecified type**

When i added 2 lines in .h file:

```
#pragma ghs startdata
extern int A;
#pragma ghs enddata
```

Above warning was gone.

So, anyone can explain to me why is that? warning was gone when i added 2 line above in header file

Comment: I have never used the Greenhills C compiler but the error message seems obvious to me and your fix the correct one. I looked at https://studylib.net/doc/25923858/greenhills-v800-compiler and it is not clear what `#pragma startdata` means without a type suffix such as `startdata-data`.  I'm guessing it defaults to `data` but regardless it seems clear the declaration in the *.h* header has to match the definition in the *.c* file.